# Changing Link Structure?

Tags: .htaccess

what to write in `.htacess` file so that i can convert the following link

```
post.php?id=$id
```

to

```
$id/something-anything
```

so that by hitting the link `$id/something-anything` it will redirect to `post.php?id=$id` automatic

I've tired this but faild

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+?)$ post.php?id=$1
```

Thanks

Why !
i want to change for example `post.php?id=4` to `4/hello-world-love-you` 
then by hitting this link `4/hello-world-love-you` it will send to another file called post.php the `id` as `4/hello-world-love-you` and by using `$realid = array_shift(explode("/", $id));` then i can get the real id of the post back which is `4` and do anything i want :) that is exactly i'm thinking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will solve your problem!

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.*) post.php?id=$1
```

Comment: @LazyOne you're right, But I tested this one on my site that has lots of rewriterules. I set that because of avoiding mixing them together!

Comment: That's pretty bad excuse. The reason is -- you are giving this not-optimal code to a person who is not familiar with URL rewriting much .. which is NOT a great start for him to learn the stuff from such code examples. On your site you can easily put such lines before all other rules and further separate from them by adding empty lines or some comment blocks.